# how to access to a server as root user with sudo in php

Tags: php, linux, terminal

If I am executing multiple commands like this

`'sudo -s && cd /apps/10.0.10.200/wso2am-1.7.0/repository/logs && tail wso2carbon.log'`

But when i'm login to the server with my user, i have to get the root permission by executing following command

```
sudo -s
```

And then I have to reenter the password also.
 So my issue is when I execute above command, how can I pass my password.Because I have to execute the command and wait until it asks to enter the password.
please guide me on that to solve. 
this is my code.

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.0.10.200');
$ssh->login('xxxxx', 'xxxx') or die("Login failed");
echo $ssh->exec('sudo -s && cd /apps/10.0.10.200/wso2am-1.7.0/repository/logs && tail wso2carbon.log');
```

Comment: That sounds like a very bad idea. What exactly do you need root permissions for? If it is just to read the log, change the ownership or permissions of that file.

Comment: but the issue is, its out of my control. So the only way is login to the server with my user and change the user role with sudo-s. So what can I to resolve this

Comment: Bad idea, but: http://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line

Answer (score 0):

This is a **very bad idea** as long as you will need to keep the user's password in your code which represent a non-negligible security issue (full remote access to the ssh server). You should have a special account on the ssh server you are connecting to that would **only** allow access to the log file you want to show.

However if you take a look at [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line) or run `sudo --help`. You'll see that you can use `sudo -S` to get the `sudo` command to read the password from stdin.

so this should do the trick:

```
$echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

using php:

```
echo $ssh->exec('echo '.$password.'| sudo -S tail /apps/10.0.10.200/wso2am-1.7.0/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log');
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your server and provide sudoers permission without password to your user.

This is highly insecure but you can edit you `/etc/sudoers` by using command `sudo visudo`

This command will open the `/etc/sudoers` file in the terminal now you can add you user entry in it using below line for executing sudoers command without password :

```
<user_name> ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Replace user_name with your user name in above line.

If your syntax goes wrong you can damage your sudoers file and hence won't be able to execute the sudo command.
If that happens use this command to rebuild your sudo file:

```
pkexec visudo
```

Then enter the sudo password.